# API endpoint works locally, returns 404 error on test server

Tags: c#, reactjs, api, .net-core, apache2

I'm having an issue with a single page application I've created using the .Net Core React template:

- UI - React
- API - .Net Core 3.1
- Test server - Apache2 on Raspberry Pi 4, app deployed as self-contained for linux-arm

My application works without a problem when I run it locally (***dotnet run*** command). However, after deploying to the test server and accessing through a browser, most of the application works except for a specific API endpoint. Whenever that endpoint is called from the UI, it always returns a 404 error. **All other API endpoints in the same controller have no errors.**

Would anyone have suggestions on how to fix this? Deployed code is simply copied over to the test server and nothing is changed. I have less experience with .net core api, so it could be something easy that I'm missing.

The UI is calling the endpoint with Javascript fetch:

```
let responseJson = await fetch(`api/rssmedia/resolvedurl/${encodedUrl}`)
                                .then((response) => response.json())
                                .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

API Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
     Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
         .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
         {
             webBuilder.UseKestrel()
                         .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                         .UseUrls("http://*:5000", "https://*:5001")
                         .UseStartup<Startup>();
         });
```

API Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options => 
    {
        options.KnownProxies.Add(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("<server IP address>"));
    });

    services.AddHttpClient();

    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

API Controller containing all endpoints, including ResolvedUrl which gets the 404 error:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class RssMediaController : ControllerBase {
    ...
    ...
    [HttpGet("{originalUrl}")]
    [ActionName("ResolvedUrl")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ResolvedUrl(string originalUrl)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the full path url that is actually called from the javascript? Curious if your app is hosted at <serveraddress> or at <serveraddress>/YourApp and the /YourApp is being left off the request.

Comment: The full url called in javascript is http://<ip>:<port>/api/rssmedia/resolvedurl/<string param>. In a web browser, I just go to http://<ip>:<port> to get to the main page.

Comment: It is caused by incorrect relative path. Can you show your derictory in apache?

Comment: For apache, I have the application in the path /var/www/<application folder>. The API dll's are in that folder, and the UI code is under /var/www/<application folder>/ClientApp/build. The apache config has the VirtualHost DocumentRoot property set to /var/www/<application folder>/ClientApp/build. Is that what you mean by show the directory? I may not have been clear, but other endpoints in the same controller are accessed without error, so I'm confused why only this endpoint has an incorrect relative path in apache.

Answer (score -1):

To find out what exactly went wrong. Try using a logger service. Or In Startup.cs configure method take out the app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); outside of the env.IsDevelopment() condition or simply comment the condition, this will help you to see the Exception details with stacktrace.